# How to style a data table in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, widget, styling

I was wondering if you could make something like this that I designed using the DataTable widget in flutter?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaHBj.png

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I actually just made a copy of the DataTable widget into a new file and I've been styling it manually from there.

Comment: share what you have done, css, etc

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can have to use Container and Table below.

1. In the below code I just cover the table with the Container widget and give the decoration property to have the radius over the border of the table.
2. Then just set the table border for inside only so it won't display the outer border which is already covered by the container.
3. And finally set the decoration property of the first TableRow(Header) widget.

You can access the sample code from
[here too.](https://gist.github.com/patelronakp/ea45aeb4a640c8c185a2f8f1cf429d7c)

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 1,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: Table(
                // border: TableBorder.all(
                //     color: Colors.black, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                border: TableBorder.symmetric(
                    inside: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black)),
                defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                columnWidths: {
                  0: FlexColumnWidth(4),
                  1: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                },
                children: [
                  TableRow(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue[100],
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                      ),
                      children: [
                    Text("Bowler", textScaleFactor: 1),
                    Text(
                      "OVR",
                      textScaleFactor: 1,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Text(score.bowler.name, textScaleFactor: 1),
                    Text(
                      score.bowler.overs.toString(),
                      textScaleFactor: 1,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can wrap with `ClipRRect` for corner radius like other widgets.**

```
ClipRRect(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
   child: Table(),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

so the issue with border-radius is that it has to be drawn only when all borders match even the inside and outside should match
it depends on isUniform method from the **TableBorder** class

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76423768/11252816) I mention a workaround for that

workaround to create a custom table border and override the isUniform method :

```dart
 
    class CustomTableBorder extends TableBorder {
      const CustomTableBorder({
        BorderSide top = BorderSide.none,
        BorderSide right = BorderSide.none,
        BorderSide bottom = BorderSide.none,
        BorderSide left = BorderSide.none,
        BorderSide horizontalInside = BorderSide.none,
        BorderSide verticalInside = BorderSide.none,
        BorderRadius borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero,
      }) : super(
              top: top,
              right: right,
              bottom: bottom,
              left: left,
              horizontalInside: horizontalInside,
              verticalInside: verticalInside,
              borderRadius: borderRadius,
            );
      factory CustomTableBorder.symmetric({
        BorderSide? inside,
        BorderSide outside = BorderSide.none,
        BorderRadius borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero,
        BorderSide? horizontalInside,
        BorderSide? verticalInside,
      }) {
        return CustomTableBorder(
          top: outside,
          right: outside,
          bottom: outside,
          left: outside,
          horizontalInside: inside ?? horizontalInside ?? BorderSide.none,
          verticalInside: inside ?? verticalInside ?? BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: borderRadius,
        );
      }
      bool get isUniform {
        final Color topColor = top.color;
        if (right.color != topColor ||
            bottom.color != topColor ||
            left.color != topColor) {
          return false;
        }
    
        final double topWidth = top.width;
        if (right.width != topWidth ||
            bottom.width != topWidth ||
            left.width != topWidth) {
          return false;
        }
    
        final BorderStyle topStyle = top.style;
        if (right.style != topStyle ||
            bottom.style != topStyle ||
            left.style != topStyle) {
          return false;
        }
    
        return true;
      }
    }
```